# TypeError: Cannot set property 'fullCalendar' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, fullcalendar

Hi I'm using fullCalendar jQuery plugin using the following react component:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import moment from 'moment';
import fullCalendar from 'fullcalendar';

class calendarApp extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
     });
  }  render(){
      return(
         <div id="calendar">
         </div>
      );
    }
}

export default calendarApp;
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
C:\Users\syedj\Desktop\newScheduler\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:28
$.fn.fullCalendar = function(options) {
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'fullCalendar' of undefined
    at C:\Users\syedj\Desktop\newScheduler\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:28:19
    at $.fullCalendar.version (C:\Users\syedj\Desktop\newScheduler\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:12:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\syedj\Desktop\newScheduler\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:17:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\syedj\Desktop\newScheduler\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:166:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (calendarApp.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at loader (C:\Users\syedj\Desktop\newScheduler\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\syedj\Desktop\newScheduler\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Calendar.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
```

I have installed jquery, moment and full calendar through npm. I still do not understand why I am getting the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is this `$('#calendar')` element present in `DOM` before you call `fullcalendar` initialization?

Comment: Since the error complains about `$.fn` being undefined it could mean that jQuery is not yet loaded. Am I right that this is server-side code? If so I guess it's not gonna work. You should use it on client.